# Dualboot Windows 11 and Linux Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS WIFI connection via Linux does not work

Tags: wireless, network-manager, connection

i have started my Laptop yesterday and it cannot connect to my Internet (via Wifi). It works with my Handy Hot Spot and with an Ethernet Connection (with the Internet that i have). I also tried another WIFI and this also not work. i tried then to reboot my System and by then it shows me: "failed to start Networkmanager". On Windows the connection to the network work fine. Here i have the Logs of my Networkmanager:

````
Jan 16 10:29:01 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[742]: <info>  [1705397341.8056] device (wlp2s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 16 10:29:01 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[742]: <info>  [1705397341.8057] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) access point '3Tube_2.4Ghz_5E09' has security, but secrets are required.
Jan 16 10:29:01 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[742]: <info>  [1705397341.8057] device (wlp2s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 16 10:29:01 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[742]: <info>  [1705397341.8058] sup-iface[0a2a1e8fd09dc1cd,1,wlp2s0]: wps: type pbc start...
Jan 16 10:29:03 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[742]: <info>  [1705397343.8281] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jan 16 10:29:03 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[742]: <info>  [1705397343.8281] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jan 16 10:29:24 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[742]: <info>  [1705397364.3095] device (wlp2s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 16 10:29:24 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[742]: <info>  [1705397364.3097] device (wlp2s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 16 10:29:24 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[742]: <info>  [1705397364.3099] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) connection '3Tube_2.4Ghz_5E09' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Jan 16 10:29:24 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[742]: <info>  [1705397364.3099] Config: added 'ssid' value '3Tube_2.4Ghz_5E09'
Jan 16 10:29:24 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[742]: <info>  [1705397364.3099] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Jan 16 10:29:24 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[742]: <info>  [1705397364.3099] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-70:86400'
Jan 16 10:29:24 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[742]: <info>  [1705397364.3099] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256 FT-PSK SAE FT-SAE'
Jan 16 10:29:24 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[742]: <info>  [1705397364.3099] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
Jan 16 10:29:24 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[742]: <info>  [1705397364.3099] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
Jan 16 10:29:24 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[742]: <info>  [1705397364.3585] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Jan 16 10:29:24 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[742]: <info>  [1705397364.3585] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Jan 16 10:29:24 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[742]: <info>  [1705397364.3663] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Jan 16 10:29:24 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[742]: <info>  [1705397364.3664] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
Jan 16 10:29:24 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[742]: <info>  [1705397364.4079] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> 4way_handshake
Jan 16 10:29:24 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[742]: <info>  [1705397364.4079] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: associating -> 4way_handshake
Jan 16 10:29:24 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[742]: <info>  [1705397364.4918] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: 4way_handshake -> completed
Jan 16 10:29:24 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[742]: <info>  [1705397364.4918] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful. Connected to wireless network "3Tube_2.4Gh>
Jan 16 10:29:24 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[742]: <info>  [1705397364.4918] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: 4way_handshake -> completed
Jan 16 10:29:24 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[742]: <info>  [1705397364.4923] device (wlp2s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 16 10:29:24 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[742]: <info>  [1705397364.4927] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Jan 16 10:30:09 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[742]: <info>  [1705397409.7669] device (wlp2s0): state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 16 10:30:09 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[742]: <info>  [1705397409.7674] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Jan 16 10:30:09 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[742]: <warn>  [1705397409.7678] device (wlp2s0): Activation: failed for connection '3Tube_2.4Ghz_5E09'
Jan 16 10:30:09 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[742]: <info>  [1705397409.7680] device (wlp2s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 16 10:30:09 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[742]: <info>  [1705397409.8232] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): canceled DHCP transaction ```

what can i do now?
````

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to resolve this but I have a work around that I am using for the same issues.  I reverted back to kernel 6.2.0-39 by selecting it from the the grub menu at startup.  The wifi works when using any 6.2.* kernel, but not  the 6.5.*. versions.

If you have autoremove'd the 6.2 kernel you can install them again with

```
sudo apt install linux-image-6.2.0-39-generic
```